# Click EditText can't popup softkeyboard

Tags: android

I open a Activity with a EditText, when I stay in this Activity, a Service in background start a new other Activity with flags:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

when the new Activity is closed, the softkeyboard can't show anymore when click the editText.

Comment: It works again when I press home button and come back again.

Comment: Have you added input type for Edit Text in your XML file?

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_add_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_50"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>  my xml

Comment: It's no use add android:inputType="text"

Comment: show your current activity and you layout XML

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this once it works for me.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
alert.setView(input);
final AlertDialog dialog = alert.show();
input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
         if(hasFocus) {
             dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE
             );
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to put the EditText in a AlertDialog.